# URL Parameter Separation

Tags: javascript, salesforce-lightning

How to use 'searchParams' so as to get multiple URL parameters separated by '&' , which also contain '&' in parameter string.

For e.g. I have a URL :
**https:*******.com?selectedCategory=Cash%2CCheques+%26+Misc%26transactionType%3dDebit**

Using the below code :

```
let pageURL = new URL(decodeURIComponent(document.URL));
const urlParams = pageURL.searchParams;
let selectedCategoryName = urlParams.get('selectedCategory');
let categoryTransType = urlParams.get('transactionType');
console.log(selectedCategoryName);
console.log(categoryTransType);
```

**selectedCategoryName returns Cash,Cheques instead of Cash, Cheques & Misc**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the URL the same, you could decode the transaction type, after you access the category parameter. I used a look-behind regular expression to split on `'&'` characters preceded by a non-space. After I have my tokens, I can shift the "head" off of the resulting list and then transform the rest of the tokens into an object.

```js
const url = new URL('https://google.com?selectedCategory=Cash%2CCheques+%26+Misc%26transactionType%3dDebit');
const selectedCategory = url.searchParams.get('selectedCategory');

const tokens = selectedCategory.split(/(?<=\S)&/g);
const head = tokens.shift();
const rest = Object.fromEntries(tokens.map(pair => pair.split('=')));

console.log(head); // Cash,Cheques & Misc
console.log(rest.transactionType); // Debit
```

---

### Notes

Your URL does appear wrong, since you encoded the `'&'` separator as `"%26"` right before `"transaction"`. Also, the `'='` was encoded as `"%3d"` following `"transaction"`.

```js
const url = new URL('https://google.com?selectedCategory=Cash%2CCheques+%26+Misc%26transactionType%3dDebit');
const selectedCategory = url.searchParams.get('selectedCategory');
console.log(selectedCategory); // Cash,Cheques & Misc&transactionType=Debit
```

This is with the altered URL:

```js
const url = new URL('https://google.com?selectedCategory=Cash%2CCheques+%26+Misc&transactionType=Debit');
const selectedCategory = url.searchParams.get('selectedCategory');
const transactionType = url.searchParams.get('transactionType');
console.log(selectedCategory); // Cash,Cheques & Misc
console.log(transactionType); // Debit
```